# Is there a cleaner way to achieve page location awareness using Angular directives?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I currently have a nav bar on my site that has 4 anchor links that link you to various places on a single page web app. When you navigate to a particular part of the page, the specific navigation anchor link lights up, indicating that you are indeed located at a particular section of the website.

***See for yourself...***
[MY WEBSITE](http://www.erikasland.com)
Note how the nav links buttons on the sidebar change as you scroll down to different sections.

I succeeded in doing this in a really bulky ugly not-so-clean manner. I made 4 directives that change each individual button as the user scrolls into its own respective range on the page.

Does anyone know how I might make cleaner more elegant directives to accomplish the same task?

***Here is my HTML***

```
<div id='dots-menu-nav'>
    <nav id='vertical-dots-menu'>
        <ul>
            <li class='nav-li'>
                <a href="" ng-click='landingControl.goToAnchor("mystory")' class='dots-menu-anchor'><span about-location class='dots-menu-dot'></span><span class='dots-menu-label'>ABOUT</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class='nav-li'>
                <a href="" ng-click='landingControl.goToAnchor("contact-tag")' class='dots-menu-anchor'><span tech-location class='dots-menu-dot'></span><span class='dots-menu-label'>TECHNOLOGIES</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class='nav-li'>
                <a href="" ng-click='landingControl.goToAnchor("projects")' class='dots-menu-anchor'><span project-location class='dots-menu-dot'></span><span class='dots-menu-label'>PROJECTS</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class='nav-li'>
                <a href="" ng-click='landingControl.goToAnchor("contact")' class='dots-menu-anchor'><span contact-location class='dots-menu-dot'></span><span class='dots-menu-label'>CONTACT</span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

***Here is my CSS...***

```
.border-black{
    border: 2px solid black;
}

.dots-menu-dot{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    top: 4px;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    float: right;
}

li:hover .dots-menu-dot{
    transform: scale(1.1);
    transition: background 0.215s ease-in-out 0s, transform 0.215s ease-in-out 0s, border 0.215s ease-in-out 0s;
    background-color: black;
    border: 2px solid white;
}

li:hover .dots-menu-label{
    color: white;
    top: 1px;
    font-family: 'WSBold'
}
```

***Here are my directives (a lot of repetition)...***

```
myModule.directive('aboutLocation', function($window){
return {
        link: function(scope, element){
            angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function() {
            var topOfScreen = $window.scrollY;
            var aboutWrap = angular.element('#mystory');
            var techWrap = angular.element('.tech-wrap');

            if(aboutWrap[0].offsetTop - 100 <= topOfScreen && topOfScreen < techWrap[0].offsetTop - 200){
                element.addClass('border-black');
            }else{
                element.removeClass('border-black');
            }
            scope.$apply();
        });
    }
}
})

myModule.directive('techLocation', function($window){
    return {
            link: function(scope, element){
                angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function() {
                var topOfScreen = $window.scrollY;
                var projectWrap = angular.element('#projects');
                var techWrap = angular.element('.tech-wrap');

                if(techWrap[0].offsetTop - 200 <= topOfScreen && topOfScreen < projectWrap[0].offsetTop - 200){
                element.addClass('border-black');
            }else{
                element.removeClass('border-black');
            }
            scope.$apply();
        });
    }
}
})

myModule.directive('projectLocation', function($window){
    return {
            link: function(scope, element){
                angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function() {
                var topOfScreen = $window.scrollY;
                var projectWrap = angular.element('#projects');
                var contactWrap = angular.element('#contact');

                if(projectWrap[0].offsetTop - 200 <= topOfScreen && topOfScreen < contactWrap[0].offsetTop - 200){
                element.addClass('border-black');
                }else{
                    element.removeClass('border-black');
                }
                scope.$apply();
            });
        }
    }
})

myModule.directive('contactLocation', function($window){
    return {
            link: function(scope, element){
                angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function() {
                var topOfScreen = $window.scrollY;
                var contactWrap = angular.element('#contact');

                if(contactWrap[0].offsetTop - 200 <= topOfScreen){
                    element.addClass('border-black');
                }else{
                    element.removeClass('border-black');
                }
                scope.$apply();
            });
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance for whatever assistance you can lend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make array of your navs [{name : ... , id : ...}, {}]. And use ng-repeat.
Second make one directive on parent 'ul' which will actually do more or less the same as your directive now. You just need add loop.
Third store currently active element, launch scope.$apply only if it changes.

Comment: Hey Petr, thanks for the help, bud. That is a great idea!